# Comparing Numpy Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, pygame

So I have two 2D numpy arrays of equal size, both obtained using the `pygame.surfarray.array3d` method on two different surfaces.

Each value in the array is also an array in the form `[a, b, c]` (so I basically have a 2D array with 1D elements).

I'd essentially like to compare the two based on the condition:

```
if any(val1 != val2) and all(val1 != [0, 0, 0]):
# can't be equal and val1 cant be [0, 0, 0]
```

Is there any more efficient way of doing this without simply iterating through either array as shown below?

```
for y in range(len(array1)):
    for x in range(len(array1[y])):
        val1 = array1[y,x]; val2 = array[y,x]
        if any(val1 != val2) and all(val1 != [0, 0, 0]):
            # do something
```

Comment: Do you actually have a 3D array whose elements are 1D arrays, or do you have a 4D array or a 3D array whose elements are of a structured dtype?

Comment: I have a 3D array whose elements are 1D arrays (I suppose that makes it a 4D array? My bad). `array[y][x]` returns `[0, 0, 0]` for example. @abarnert

Comment: That's a 2D array with 1D elements if my counting is alright...

Comment: Alright, my terminology is clearly terrible haha. So, I'm basically looking to compare the elements of two 2D arrays.

Comment: If `array[y][x]` returns `[0, 0, 0]` then you have a 3D array of numbers (or a 2D array of 1D arrays), not a 3D array of 1D arrays.

Comment: Question updated for clarity @abarnert. You're right, I apologise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
if np.any(array1 != array2) and not np.any(np.all(a == 0, axis=-1))
```

`np.any(array1 != array2)` is comparing each element of the "big" 3D array. This is, however, equivalent to comparing `val1` to `val2` for every `x` and `y`.

The other condition, `np.any(np.all(a == 0, axis=-1))` is a little bit more complicated. The innermost `np.all(a == 0, axis=-1)` creates a 2D array of boolean values. Each value is set to `True` or `False` depending if **all** values in the last dimension are `0`. The outer condition checks if any of the values in the 2D array are `True` which would mean that there was an element of `array1[y, x]` that was equal to `[0, 0, 0]`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to everything numpy so I appreciate your patience.

Comment: I think this might need a bit of explanation—`array != array2` isn't specifically comparing each `array1[x][y]`, but rather comparing each `array1[x][y][index]`, but that ends up having the right effect, while the latter one _is_ comparing each `array[x][y]`… but I'm sure you can put it better than that (and hopefully without resorting to non-numpy-style indexing, too).

Comment: @abarnert _"non-numpy-style indexing"_ :-)